# Bootstrap navpanel and date picker with javascript call to C# controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a some code that allows a user to enter a data into a bootstrap datepicker and then click the submit button and date is shown inside a navpanel.  On button click I have a javascript function that will determine which tab the user is on, and will run a C# function in an MVC controller.  I currently have two functions DelayedSpiffDate, InstantSpiffDate.  For some reason it will only load the DelayedSpiffDate function even if the instantspiff tab is selected.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?  Here's my html:

```
<div class="row-fluid 1">
    <div class="col-lg-12 delayed_spiff_body">

        <div class="row spiff-datepicksection">
            <div class="col-lg-6 pull-right">
                <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-offset-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group date">
                            <input type="text" id="startDate" class="form-control" />
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <input class="spiffdate-btn" type="button" value="Submit" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row spiff_tabs_body">
            <!-- Nav tabs -->
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs spiff_tabs" role="tablist">
                <li role="presentation" class="active">
                    <a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-id="delayedspiff" data-toggle="tab" onclick="FormGet('dashboard/delayedspiff', 'delayedspiff')">Potential Spiff</a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-id="instantspiff" data-toggle="tab" onclick="FormGet('dashboard/instantspiff', 'delayedspiff')">Instant Spiff</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Tab panes -->
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="delayedspiff"></div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="instantspiff"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's my javascript:

```
 $(".spiffdate-btn").click(function(){
var correctid = $(".tab-content .active").attr("id");
var startDate = $("#startDate").val();
if (correctid == "delayedspiff")
    $.get("@Url.Action("DelayedSpiffDate", "Dashboard")", { startDate: startDate });
else
    $.get("@Url.Action("InstantSpiffDate", "Dashboard")", { startDate: startDate });
});
```

Updated javascript:

```
$(".spiffdate-btn").click(function(){
   var correctId = $("ul.spiff_tabs li.active a").attr('data-id');
   console.log(correctId);

   var startDate = $("#startDate").val();

   if (correctId == "delayedspiff")
   {          
       $.get("@Url.Action("DelayedSpiffDate", "Dashboard")", { startDate: startDate });

   } else if (correctId == "instantspiff") {

       $.get("@Url.Action("InstantSpiffDate", "Dashboard")", { startDate: startDate });
   }
```

});

Comment: Check if you get the right id in `correctid` add for example `console.log(correctid)` before condition.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I am not getting the correct id on correctid.  It shows delayedspiff even if the instantspiff tab is selected.

Comment: I'm getting correct ID. Problem is the $.get should fail because the first argument is multi strings instead of one encapsulated.

Comment: @Brant I don't understand?  What code are you using to get the correct ID?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Check updated answer I posted.

Comment: @Brant I checked your answer.  I'm still having an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are targeting the wrong item if you want it based on the clicked tab... Try this as your 'getter':

```
var correctId = $("ul.spiff_tabs li.active a").attr('data-id');
```

Comment: I'm getting squiggly lines and an error message when I change it to single quotes like you have.  Error is Too many characters in character literal.  I'm not sure what escaping is?  I'm pretty new to javascript.

Comment: Ok I tried this.  Now when I click the button nothing is happening?  I copied my new javascript code that includes what you suggested in my question.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm getting the correct id's back in the console.log.  I'm not sure why it's not running the Url.Action though.  It never makes it to the C# code.

Comment: $.get("@Url.Action(\"DelayedSpiffDate\", \"Dashboard\")", { startDate: startDate }); // try that

Comment: that gives me squiggly lines and errors.  It seems to want another ), but I'm not sure where to put it?

Comment: @Brant Razor statements shouldn't be escaped

Comment: I finally go tit.  It was a couple of typos in my code.  @Brant your code is correct.  It worked once I was using the right operator and fixed the typo.  Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code in this point, your second param in `FormGet` is wrong, change it from `delayedspiff` to `instantspiff`:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs spiff_tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active">
        <a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-id="delayedspiff" data-toggle="tab" onclick="FormGet('dashboard/delayedspiff', 'delayedspiff')">Potential Spiff</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
        <a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-id="instantspiff" data-toggle="tab" onclick="FormGet('dashboard/instantspiff', 'instantspiff')">Instant Spiff</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Marcus I did this, but it still doesn't work.  It still runs the delayedspiffdate function no matter which tab is selected.

Comment: She hasn't posted the code for formGet() so we don't know what the second arg does in that function.

Comment: @Brant the formGet() function just loads the forms inside of the tabs.  It doesn't have anything to do with what I'm working on now.

Comment: That's what I explained in my comment.

Comment: I tho thought set `.active` on the tab. Cuz your problem is in this part `var correctid = $(".tab-content .active").attr("id");`

Comment: @MarcusAbrahão what is the problem in that part?

Comment: Cuz it seems that the first `.tab-pane` is always the `.active` one.

Comment: @MarcusAbrahão I'm not sure that is the problem.  I took active off of the 1st tab and it still does the same thing.

Comment: @MarcusAbrahão I created one.  Not sure how helpful it will be but it includes all my code.    https://jsfiddle.net/a3vd1uay/

Comment: @MarcusAbrahão I don't know if this is helpful, but I realized when I debug the app I'm getting an error message: Uncaught ReferenceError: correctid is not defined.  I'm getting a value back for correctid though so I'm not sure what this means?